# SQLlite foreign key

Tags: sqlite

Подскажите из-за чего появляется ошибка - **Error while committing new row: foreign key mismatch - "Recipe" referencing "Flavor_id"**

```
CREATE TABLE Recipe (
id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name      TEXT    DEFAULT Recip,
pg        INTEGER,
vg        INTEGER,
nicotine  INTEGER,
bottesize INTEGER,
flavor_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
date      DATE,
note      TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY (flavor_id)
REFERENCES Flavor_id (flavor_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION
                                 ON UPDATE NO ACTION
                                 MATCH SIMPLE
);

CREATE TABLE Flavor_id (
    id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name      TEXT,
    drops     INTEGER,
    flavor_id INTEGER
);
```

Данные:
Flavor_id table

```
|id|name|drops|flavor_id|
|1 |ing1|  0  |    1    |
|2 |ing2|  0  |    1    |
|3 |ing3|  0  |    1    |
|4 |ing4|  0  |    2    |
```

Данные:
Recipe table

```
|id|  name | pg | vg | nicotine | bottlesize |flavor_id|date|note|
|1 |recipe1|  0 | 1  |    0     |    30      |    1    | -  |  - |
|2 |recipe2|  0 | 1  |    0     |    15      |    2    | -  |  - |
```

Один рецепт может соответствовать нескольким ингредиентам. Например **flavor_id 1** содержит три ингредиента

Comment: покажите вставляемые данные, на которых падает ошибка

Comment: Вам объясняют, что то значение, которое Вы вставляете в `Recipe.Flavor_id`, отсутствует в `Flavor_id.flavor_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Значение должно быть UNIQUE согласно документации http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes